# Setting radio buttons in gridview unclickable

Tags: java, android, radio-button, android-gridview

I got this grid-view in a fragment which is dynamicaly populated with a radio buttons via adapter that extends `BaseAdapter`. The adapter uses View-Holder pattern to populate that `gridView`. 
 I wanna set all of those buttons to be unclickable until some other button outside that `gridView` is clicked. 
I've tried to reference that `gridView` and use methods `setEnabled(false)` and `setClickable(false)`, but it doesn't work. 
I tried looping through the gridView with  `for(int i = 0; i < gridView.getChildCount(); i++){
            ((RadioButton)gridView.getChildAt(i)).setEnabled(false);`

That `radioButton` that populates the `gridView` dinamycaly is wraped by `RelativeLayout`  
 Should I use different approach to access the child views?

Comment: Are you not getting any error like classcastexception if radiobutton is wrapped by relativelayout and you try to gridView.getChildAt(i) to RadioButton ?

Comment: `getChildAt()` returns an object of type `View`. `View` already has the method `setClickable()`, so casting to a `RadioButton` is not needed.

Comment: @GiantTree  how so,  its referenced right here : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setEnabled(boolean)

Comment: @Markonionini  post the getView of the grid adapter you are using.

Comment: @petey Sorry, I am not able to access the source code right now.

Comment: @dora I am not quiet sure if I am casting it in a source code, it is acctualy my work assignment and I am not able to access it right now.

Comment: @petey Thanks for the hint, I set those buttons unclickable in getView method.